# How to upload database.aqlite file to Google Drive from iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, google-drive-api

I am working with Xcode  and need some help with google drive SDK for ios

1. How can I upload database.aqlite file to Google Drive from iOS?
2. How to update existing file on the Drive? Check if the file exist and just update/replace the database file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can find information on uploading and modifying files in [Working with file contents](https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/devguide/files#writing_files) guide in the developer documentation.